# egrep multiple AND's with a range query

Tags: linux, grep

I'm trying to get a list of ports that have been occupied by a php service within a defined range.

this seems to work ok..

```
lsof | grep -E 'php.+55000.+LISTEN'
php       6446  user   11u     IPv4             694089      0t0        TCP *:55000 (LISTEN)
```

But when I make it a range query it doesn't seem to give the correct results

```
lsof | grep -E 'php.+[55000-55001].+LISTEN'
php       6446  user   11u     IPv4             694089      0t0        TCP *:55000 (LISTEN)
php       6446  user   12u     IPv4             694090      0t0        TCP *:51000 (LISTEN)
```

Please help, my regex skills are amateur.

Comment: So you want port php any php process running on port 55000 and 55001 ? is it?

Comment: I want to know if there are any processes running on that port range, yes. 51000 shouldn't be appearing in the results.

Comment: ok. lsof -i :55000-55001 

On the man page it says you can use -i option and pass a port range :)

Comment: Ahh! awesome, no idea why I didn't look there. Thanks so much. Do you want to add it as an answer an I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you looking for is  `lsof -i` option. On the man page it says:

```
To list all files using any protocol on ports 513, 514, or 515 of host wonderland.cc.purdue.edu, use:

       lsof -i @wonderland.cc.purdue.edu:513-515
```

So for your case you can start with:

```
lsof -i :55000-55001
```

And than use all the grep you need to get your answer.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

does this work for you? (port range 55000-60000)

```
lsof|awk '$2>55000 && $2<60000 && /php/ && /LISTEN/'
```